# Complex JAXB unmarshalling into more than object

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am new to JAXB and am currently working on a project which requires unmarshalling a complex XML in to more than one nested objects. For example suppose I have following XML

```xml
 <person>
     <bio>
          <id>12345</id>
          <name>Keth TTT</name>
          <age>30</age>
     </bio>
     <address>
           <no>1232</no>
           <street>York Street</street>
           <city>NewYork<city>
           <country>USA</country>
     </address>
 </person>
```

and suppose i have following domain objects

```java
class Person{
    String id;
    String name;
    int age;
    Address address;
}
```

and

```java
class Address{
    String name;
    String no;
    String street;
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

If the XSD is mtaching or have the matching structure, JAXB will easily populate those POJOs. But in here we need to do complex mapping(Ex: both `Person` and `Address` classes contain same attribute name). How can we travel through these objects and populate both objects?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension for your use case.  Your `Person` class would look something like:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotations*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person{

    @XmlPath("bio/id/text()")
    String id;

    @XmlPath("bio/name/text()")
    String name;

    @XmlPath("bio/age/text()")
    int age;

    Address address;
}
```

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html